# How can I compare models with the NADA package in R?

Tags: r

From the error message below I'm guessing the "step" function does not work with an mle, which is an S4 class?

I can get the step function to choose the best model by AIC for an lm, and it says it should also work for glm's, but so far I've only seen mle's in the Non Detects and Data Analysis (NADA) package I'm using. About 20% of my outcome data (Arsenic in W. Nevada groundwater) was below the detection limit.

The "step" code is far simpler than some other code I've seen for comparing AIC's for models one by one, but I guess I'll see if the latter will work with the NADA package.

The NADA package provides a x2 test to compare models, but for some reason all my models have huge x2's with p=0, so I don't know how to compare this way either (example below). However, I'm not very familiar with x2 tests, stats, or R in general. The NADA author mentions choosing the best model best on the "partial log likelihood."

Thanks!

EXCERPTS OF MY CODE SO FAR:

```
install.packages("NADA")
library(NADA)
As_nada_mle=with(clean2503, cenreg(Cen(As001, nd_epa)~Elev_m + Tahoe + Walker + UpperCarson + Tcan2car + TruckeeTribOrMain))
Best_nada=step(As_nada_mle)
##Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

EXAMPLE OF MY NADA PACKAGE CENREG OUTPUT:

```
                     Value Std. Error       z        p
(Intercept)       11.03589     4.1515  2.6583 7.85e-03
Elev_m            -0.00825     0.0013 -6.3453 2.22e-10
Tahoe              0.29773     4.8417  0.0615 9.51e-01
Walker             1.36853     3.9538  0.3461 7.29e-01
UpperCarson       -2.13845     3.9506 -0.5413 5.88e-01
Tcan2car           2.56088     3.9238  0.6527 5.14e-01
TruckeeTribOrMain -2.98352     4.0807 -0.7311 4.65e-01
Log(scale)         1.36526     0.0171 79.7684 0.00e+00

Scale = 3.92 

Log Normal distribution

Loglik(model)= -12303.8   Loglik(intercept only)= -12982.3 
Loglik-r:  0.64693 

Chisq= 1357.07 on 6 degrees of freedom, p= 0 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5 
n = 2503
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have technical experience with what you are trying to do. With
that caveat, here are my thoughts:

1. It seems like the difficulty is trying to run the step wrapper on
   your cenreg command. Since step is simply a convenience algorithm to
   automatically select the best AIC, it is not strictly necessary. Thus
   another way to go would be to make a table of all the possible models
   you want to consider (these should be mechanistically plausible), and
   determine the AIC and/or log liklihood of each one, and then compare
   them and pick the best. This is often done in the "information
   theoretic" approach that uses AIC. This approach has a standard way to
   do it - I could send you some examples if you need it. Its also
   outlined in Burnham KP, Anderson DR. 2002. Model Selection and
   Multimodel Inference: A Practical Information-Theoretic Approach. 2nd
   ed. Berlin, Germany: Springer. (Berkeley has this as an ebook). An
   advantage is that you see whats going on in terms of which parameters
   seem to matter in various circumstances. The only case this would be
   really impractical is if you are comparing dozens and dozens of
   different kinds of models.
2. The reason the x2 is so significant is probably because it is for
   the overall model, for which you have a presumably large sample size
   and several terms that fit. I'm assuming the x2 is somehow comparing
   the two log likelihoods, and we see a difference between:
   Loglik(model)= -12303.8   Loglik(intercept only)= -12982.3
3. You probably realize this, but right now there are a lot of
   non-significant terms in your model (p > 0.1) : if you run another
   model excluding them, your logliklihood will improve a lot (i.e., get
   less negative).
4. Maybe Dennis Helsel's textbook on censored data would help
   interpret how to use cenreg?

People less ignorant than I are out there, and they can correct or improve on my suggestions...